# Get centroid of SimpleFeatures in GeoTools8

Tags: java, geotools

I've got some SimpleFeatureCollections and now I want to get the Centroid of every SimpleFeature in the collection.
Unfortunally I've only found a centroid method for Geometry.

Is there any way to get the centroid?

Comment: Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getAttribute("the_geom");    System.out.println(geom.getCentroid()); this works for me

Answer (score 1):

Simply, iterate through the collection and fetch the defaultGeometry attribute from each feature.

```
   try (SimpleFeatureIterator it2 = selection.features()) {
      while (it2.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f2 = it2.next();
        Point p = ((Geometry) f2.getDefaultGeometry()).getCentroid();
      }
    }
```